# Метод clone в плагинах поведения .droppable и .draggable

Tags: jquery, ui

Здравствуйте люди добрые. Помогите разобраться. Есть левая колонка в которой находиться картинки и они могут быть перетаскиваемы .draggable и есть основной контент который принимает те самые картинки .droppable, картинки клонируются в контент методом clone и снова стают перетаскиваемые. Но проблема в том что когда они перетаскиваются в контенте они продолжают клонироваться. А это мне совсем не нужно. Как исправить код?

html код

```
<div id="wraper">
  <div id="heder"></div>
  <div id="saitbar">
    <div id="element1" ><img src="images/1.png" width="100" height="100" alt="подсказка" /></div>
    <div id="element2" ><img src="images/2.png" width="100" height="100" alt="подсказка" /></div>
    <div id="element3" ><img src="images/3.png" width="100" height="100" alt="подсказка" /></div>
    <!--<div id="element4" ><img src="images/1.png" width="100" height="100" alt="подсказка" /></div>
    <div id="element5" ><img src="images/2.png" width="100" height="100" alt="подсказка" /></div>
    <div id="element6" ><img src="images/3.png" width="100" height="100" alt="подсказка" /></div>
    <div id="element7" ><img src="images/1.png" width="100" height="100" alt="подсказка" /></div>
    <div id="element8" ><img src="images/2.png" width="100" height="100" alt="подсказка" /></div>
    <div id="element9" ><img src="images/3.png" width="100" height="100" alt="подсказка" /></div>-->
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="contener" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
  </div>
```

js код

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // перетаскивание
    $('div[id*=element]').draggable({ 
        containment: "#wraper",
        revert: "invalid", 
        grid: [ 20,20 ],
        opacity: 0.5,
        scroll:false,
        zIndex: 35,
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move",
        stack:"div[id*=element]"
    });
    //приемник 
    $( "#contener" ).resizable().droppable({
        accept: "div[id*=element]",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var element = $(ui.draggable);
            element.fadeIn(1000, function() {
                $(this).clone()
                .addClass("newElement") 
                .appendTo("#contener")
                .draggable()
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: нажмите редактировать, выделите текст кода и нажмите {} повторяйте с вариациями, пока текст в preview не будет читабельным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поправьте у `droppable` какие элементы принимаются, указав источник:

```
$( "#contener" ).resizable().droppable({
    accept: "#saitbar > div[id*=element]"
    ...
});
```

Comment: Спосибо огромное, очень помогли.

Comment: не за что :)

Comment: Подскажите Павел, как можно сделать так чтобы контенер droppable можно было сахранять вмести совсе содержимым, которое в него накидали, на компьютер в виде картинки или pdf?

Comment: Кусок html нельзя сохранить в виде картинки. Зато можно с помощью <canvas>, может быть вам больше подойдет он?

Comment: @dmivasant: как сказал @MrFranke, напрямую сделать этого никак нельзя.